# How to make Product Images visible in Partner Community when user selects "Add Products" on an opportunity

Tags: lightning-community, partner-communities, images, file-sharing

I uploaded images to "Files" and created to Fields on the Product Object, "Product Image"(Formula) and "Product Image Link"(Text255).  My formula below displays images on my products internally but as a commmunity partner user I am unable to see them.  I get a broken image icon.

Formula - IMAGE("https://bhb--clone--c.documentforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Png&versionId="+Product_Image_Link__c, "", 110,180)

Comment: Due to the separation of the community from the internal side of your org, either the URL format is invalid in a community context or your community users have insufficient permissions to access the image.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a long time ago with documents not files.
But it required hard coded document links within the product record. I suppose that data entry could be automated.

**For files you should use the public link button:**
Should look something like this:
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/6D000000xxxx/a/6D000000xxxx/wGZxx.g2dxljpWOrzcOvhDYTv4Jvw6SAEHsgzV8xxxx